# Uploading images/files inside a PWA

Tags: android, file-upload, android-manifest, progressive-web-apps

I've build a PWA using PWABuilder from Microsoft, and created some webpages to show those within the PWA. On one of those pages the user should be able to upload images/files, within the browser it works fine, but inside my "app" nothing happens if the user clicks on "upload file".

Actually I am using Gravityforms for Wordpress to upload images, but since its not working I researched and found

`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`

but it isn't working neither.

In the Android manifest I'm getting permission to access media storage and camera

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

still not working.

Does anyone has an suggestion what else I could try?